# How to extract a unicode text inside a tag?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to collect data for my lab from this website: [link](https://www.coursera.org/learn/applied-data-science-capstone-ar)

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url='https://www.coursera.org/learn/applied-data-science-capstone-ar'
html=requests.get(url).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

info=soup.find('div',class_='_1wb6qi0n')

title=info.find('h1',class_='banner-title banner-title-without--subtitle m-b-0')

print(title)
```

I expect `title` would be `كابستون علوم البيانات التطبيقية`
but the result is `Ù…Ù†Ù‡Ø¬ÙŠØ© Ø¹Ù„Ù… Ø§Ù„Ø¨ÙŠØ§Ù†Ø§Øª`.

What is the problem? And how do I fix it?

Thank you for taking time to answer.

Comment: add  a `.decode('utf-8')` at the end of the `find()` function and see if it resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a nice library called `ftfy`. It has multiple language support.

**Installation:** `pip install ftfy`

**Try this:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ftfy

import requests


url='https://www.coursera.org/learn/applied-data-science-capstone-ar'
html=requests.get(url).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

info=soup.find('div',class_='_1wb6qi0n')

title=info.find('h1',class_='banner-title banner-title-without--subtitle m-b-0').text
title = ftfy.fix_text(title)

print(title)
```

**Output:**

```
كابستون علوم البيانات التطبيقية
```

Comment: You can fix this without importing extra library by set the encoding to `UTF-8` See the other answers.

Comment: we can that too and i know that

Answer (score 4):

The issue you are facing is due to improper encoding when fetching the URL using `requests.get()` function. By default the pages requested via `requests` library have a default encoding of `ISO-8859-1` which results in the incorrect encoding of the html itself. In order to force a proper encoding for the requested page, you need to change the encoding using the `encoding` attribute of the requested page. For this to work the line `requests.get(url).text` has to be broken like so:

```
...

# Request the URL and store the request
request = requests.get(url)

# Change the encoding before extracting the text
# Automatically infer encoding
request.encoding = request.apparent_encoding

# Now extract the HTML as text
html = request.text

...
```

In the above code snippet, `request.apparent_encoding` will automatically infer the encoding of the page without having to forcefully specify one or the other encoding.

So, the final code would be as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.coursera.org/learn/applied-data-science-capstone-ar'

request = requests.get(url)
request.encoding = request.apparent_encoding
html = request.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
info = soup.find('div',class_='_1wb6qi0n')
title = info.find('h1',class_='banner-title banner-title-without--subtitle m-b-0')

print(title.text)
```

PS: You must call `title.text` before printing to print the inner content of the tag.

**Output:**

```
كابستون علوم البيانات التطبيقية
```

Answer (score 2):

What were causing the error is the encoding of the html data.

Arabic letters need 2 bytes to show

You need to set html data encoding to `UTF-8`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url='https://www.coursera.org/learn/applied-data-science-capstone-ar'
html=requests.get(url)
html.encoding = html.apparent_encoding
soup=BeautifulSoup(html.text,'lxml')

info=soup.find('div',class_='_1wb6qi0n')

title=info.find('h1',class_='banner-title banner-title-without--subtitle m-b-0').get_text()

print(title)
```

In above `apparent_encoding` will automatically set the encoding to what suits the data

***OUTPUT :***

```
كابستون علوم البيانات التطبيقية
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use UTF8 encoding/decoding! and if your problem is in terminal i think you have no solution, but if your result environment is in another environment like web pages, you can see true that!